# EXCEL: Additional COUNTIFS / Condition Needed for Value Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am recording multiple channels from individually housed birds, and sometimes their vocalizations bleed-through to other channels.

I want them to be tagged for removal in some way. Testing/eyeballing the data shows that identical Begin Time for the vocalization (Column B) with the weakest Power(dB) (Column C) can be tagged using:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C,">" & $C2)
```

Since the louder vocalization starting at the same time as others belongs to the bird that originated it, and not an artifact of their proximity.

Searching around and reading superuser helped me come up with that on my own and it works great for me.

I'm not sure how the logic works, but I want to add to it so only birds grouped in the ranges 1-8 (Cabinet 1), 9-17 (Cabinet 2), 18-24 (Cabinet 3) in Column A (Channels) receive the formula I have working-- so that only birds within the first cabinet / Column A range are compared to one another with my functional COUNTIFS formula, and so on for the other two boxes. I think it might be simple but I'm not sure what even to search for.

I also hope I have typed this clearly, please let me know what other information you might need from me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that column A has numbers and you want to search within a specific range then try this version for "Cabinet 1" (only usin rows with 1-8 in column A)

`=COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C,">" & $C2, A:A,">=1",A:A,"<=8")`

Change as required for other ranges